# How to get icon buttons inside Apper software manager when used in Lxqt

Tags: 18.04, icons, appearance, lxqt

I was looking for a light and fast software manager for KDE/Qt similar to Synaptic, and Apper is an answer.

Although it is usable, and I find it even lighter than Synaptic, it lacks icons for the buttons of various actions when I am trying to use it in LXQT desktop environment (installed on top of Kubuntu 18.04).

In Plasma it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

but in LXQT like this:

[image]

[image]

---

### Update after answer suggesting the icon set may be the problem:

This seems to be a problem with it running outside Plasma/KDE or with it running in LXQT:

- the same icon set was used in Plasma and LXQT.
- if, in LXQT, I open Apper and then open the Appearance settings to change the icon set, Apper shows its icons, **with any icon set**. But after restarting Apper, it has no icons, **no matter the selected icon set** .

---

I am yet to test in a third desktop environment. I was not able to install it in Mate, for example, due to needed dependencies incompatible with local packages.

Comment: You can also try [Muon](https://askubuntu.com/a/1000768/66509), it supports [package pinning](https://askubuntu.com/a/1002760/66509).

Comment: @N0rbert - thanks for remembering it to me. It was already installed but I had forgotten about it. It looks even closer to Synaptic. But I still like Apper and would like an answer here.

Comment: @N0rbert - that's off-topic here, but I have some problems with Muon in lxqt too. It fails to show updates, unlike Apper and Synaptic, without telling me why. But I don't want to insist on that here.

Comment: @cipricos just tried to inform you. I have already vote up for both current question and answer here :)

Comment: @N0rbert - thanks again. "off-topic here" was meant to my "problems" detailed here, not your comment.

Answer (score 2):

By default, my Apper looks like this:

[image: Apper default]

If I look in `System Settings` > `Icons`, I have:

[image: Default Icon theme Breeze]

But if I change the icon theme to `Adwaita`, I see some blank spaces:

[image: Adwaita]

I suggest you stay with Breeze. If, for some reason, it's missing from your system, `sudo apt install breeze-icon-theme` should make it available.

Comment: I have updated my question after testing in Plasma, in fact I was using it in LXQT on top of Kubuntu. Sorry for this delay. But it still may be the icon set.

Comment: Your answer shows what you have in Plasma, wright? This question is on Apper in LXQT though.

Comment: I have up-voted it, do NOT delete it, as my question was updated in relation to it. I just think your comment was necessary in order to make clear that the answer is on Plasma and therefore that I cannot accept it for the question as it stands now.

Comment: I will do it maybe. For the moment I have this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1079211/47206. I have also posted various tweaks here and on U&L on LXQT. Searching based on my username and lxqt will bring those forth: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A32012+lxqt and https://askubuntu.com/search?q=user%3A47206+lxqt

Comment: I see that under U&L I have already a few Lxqt QnA. I guess that is the most preferable way to address such topics, not in one single QnA. - As for why I changed from Plasma to Lxqt: Plasma was a bit slow compared to other DEs like Xfce, Kwin crushing all the time, with poor wifi stability. Lxqt with Kwin was a great experience, with kwin **never** crashing. I like the looks with the Dark lxqt theme and with Oxigen, Breeze or Kvantum widget styles (common to Plasma).

Comment: Even wifi experience improved: initially there was no wifi manager in my lxqt session (maybe I have missed installing something) and I installed wicd which added more stability (but broke networkmanager when logging to Plasma, because wicd uses I think wpa_supplicant instead). Recently I removed wicd in favor of nm-tray (a networmanager tool) and all is well. - But I guess installing Lxqt as I did would bring the need for a lot of tweaks.